# Continuous function in rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Suppose $f:Q\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, where $Q=[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]\times\ldots\times[a_n,b_n]\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $f$ is integrable over $Q$.

Since $Q$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is compact. Therefore $f$ is uniformly continuous. The Riemann condition tells us that we have to prove that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a partition $P$ of $Q$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$. Equivalently, there exists a partition $P$ of $Q$ such that $$\left|\sum_Rv(R)(M_R(f)-m_R(f))\right|<\epsilon,$$ where $M_R(f)$ is the supremum of the values of $f$ inside the rectangle $R$, and $m_R(f)$ is the corresponding value for infimum. (Here, $R$ ranges over all subrectangles formed by the partition $P$.)

Comment: The definition of an integral with upper and lower sums is actually the Darboux integral. The Riemann integral is defined using tagged partitions. It all comes down to the same thing in the end, but that is a theorem and must be proven. You're not in bad company: Even Rudin cheats at this in one of his books! (In the proof of the formula for change of variables in multiple integrals, IIRC)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: K just cuz there's no question mark doesn't mean we can't figure out what he/she wants...."Show that $f$  is integrable over $Q$". Guess they want help with that part.

Comment: So use uniform continuity and finish the job, your partition should consist of pieces of diameter $< \delta$ , $\delta$ coming from the definition of uniform continuity applied to a target $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Spaderdabomb I can fathom at least three different questions here: 1) Solve the exercise stated at the top. 2) Complete the beginning of solution to solve the exercise stated at the top. 3) Check whether the beginning of solution is correct.

Comment: Why are you telling me this, I'm in agreement with you here! It should be copper.hat you're telling that lol

Comment: Do you want the details of the proof ?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to complete the solution... Evan's hint did that. Thanks all.

Comment: @Spaderdabomb No it is you I "should be telling that lol". You pretend there is a *unique* (obvious) question corresponding to this post while there are at least three *different* ones.

Comment: Pretty clear what the main question was to me. I don't know what you're reading. Sure there's some sub questions, but clearly the main question is right at the top. Second sentence.

Comment: @Spaderdabomb Pretty clear (now) that the question is NOT "Show that f is integrable over Q" but rather how to make the tentative solution expanded in the post work (this was made explicit in the comments). "I don't know what you're reading"... That, which is on the page (you should try sometimes). (Unrelated: use @.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the uniform continuity theorem, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $Q$.
Thus, given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that when $\mathbf x,\mathbf y \in Q$ and $||\mathbf x-\mathbf y||<\delta$, then $|f(\mathbf x)-f(\mathbf y)|<\varepsilon/v(Q)$.
Let $m$ be so large that the $||\mathbf a-\mathbf b||$ divided by $m$ is less than $\delta$ and consider the mth regular partition of $Q\,$ (defined in an obvious way).
Then, using the extreme value theorem, you have$$\left|\sum_Rv(R)(M_R(f)-m_R(f))\right|<\epsilon,$$ where $R$ ranges over all the subrectangles of the partition and $M_R(f)$ is the supremum and $m_R(f)$ the infimum of $f$ over $R$.
Therefore, by the Riemann criterion, $f$ is integrable over $Q$.